# Rails collection_select does not save all values in params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, roles

So, I'm trying to implement simple role based authentication system using Rails and I'm having a problem with final step - changing roles.

`role` is attribute in `user` table and it has a `string` type.

Idea is that some users with some privilages have ability to change roles.

Code in `view` looks like this:

```
<div>
    <%= f.label :role, 'Role' %>
    <%= f.collection_select :role, User::ROLES, :to_s, :humanize, 
                             prompt: 'Select role' %>
</div>
```

`update` method in `users_controller` looks like this:

```
def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update(update_params) #update_params is method that returns permitted parameters
        redirect_to @user   
    else
        render :edit
    end
end
```

Problem is that `user[role]` is empty after submitting a form.

Everything is pretty much made "by the book". Also, I am using Cancan but it's turned off for `edit` and `update` with `load_and_authorize_resource :except => [:update, :edit]`.

Answer (score 1):

So, I've found a solution. Since I'm using CanCan and `user_params` method so CanCan itself can set permitted parameters, my `update_params` method is ignored.

Solution is to add `:role` to `user_params` method.